# Is there a CSS way to scale an image to fill available space between two other block-level elements on an A4 page?

Tags: html, css, printing

I'm attempting to generate a series of pages to be printed on A4, using information that varies from record to record. Each record is to be printed on one page.

Each page should have the following layout (mockup not to scale):

[image: Layout mockup]

- The header is of fixed size for each record.
- The central image may be of any size and aspect ratio and should scale to fit the available space.
- The data rows in the footer at the bottom may be of any number, but one can assume they will not fill the entire page. (It would be acceptable to scale their containing table to fit a specific proportion of the page, say 25%, if it was necessary to do so to allow the image to be scaled.)

This feels as if it should be relatively simple to achieve, but as yet, I hve not been able to do so with pure CSS. Is there a simple solution that I am overlooking? Otherwise, is JS necessary?

An acceptable solution would be one that conforms to the 210:297 ratio without enforcing width and height of 210mm and 297mm - once it is in the right ratio, the scaling to fit an A4 page could be left to the browser's printing facility.

Comment: Yes, you can , look into `background-size`. additionally you can turn on print view emulation  which will show you what your printer will print

Comment: @ImmortalDude Thanks, this has led me to the `object-fit` property, which looks promising.

Comment: @ImmortalDude Although `object-fit` or `background-size` work well for adjusting the size of the central image, there is still an issue in that the footer is of variable size, depending on how many data rows there are. It therefore is not possible to specify a height for the centre image area, and `object-fit` does not work without `height` also being specified. Is there any way of replicating the effect of `object-fit` on the textual contents of a `div`?

Comment: Try splitting the page into three parts using flex divs that should work

Comment: @ImmortalDude Footer text still spills out of the [footer](https://jsfiddle.net/SpinnerWebs/znf1cs93/).

Comment: Don't give a fixed height to your image container, let it "flex" to fill the available space

Comment: @ImmortalDude Removing height from the centre image container prevents `object-fit` [from working](https://jsfiddle.net/SpinnerWebs/znf1cs93/10/).

Comment: dont use an `img` tag, instead use a `<div>` with the background url pointing to your  image and apply the background position to that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will help you to show an image that occupies the remaining space in the body. The amount of space the image occupies depends on the space remaining which is inline with your question. Modify as per as your needs

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.print-body {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  color: white;
  background-color: #f90;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.image {
  display: flex;
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/1280x720);
  margin: 10px 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="print-body">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="item">item # 1</div>
    <div class="item">item # 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```